# How to create elasticsearch watcher by xpack

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I just tried working with elasticsearch and now trying to create first watcher

There are some information I have read in elasticsearch documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/watcher-getting-started.html

And now I trty to create one :

```
https://es.origin-test.cloud.rccf.ru/apiconnect508/_xpack/watcher/watch/audit_watch
```

> PUT method + auth headers

I put in :

```
{   "trigger" : {
        "schedule": {
            "interval": "1h"
        }
    },  "actions" : {       "send_email" : { 
            "email" : { 
                "to" : "ext_avolkova@rencredit.ru", 
                "subject" : "Watcher Notification", 
                "body" : "{{ctx.payload.hits.total}}  logs found" 
            }       }   } }
```

But now I see mistake :

> No handler found for uri
>   [/apiconnect508/_xpack/watcher/watch/log_audit] and method [PUT]

Please, help me to create one simple watcher

Comment: Why do you have apiconnect508? Is that your index? The URI should start with _xpack.

Comment: @harishkb yes, it is. When i find mapping, i do it after this index and it's working

Comment: watchers are not bound to any indices storing data. You should not provide your index name. Instead try `PUT https://es.origin-test.cloud.rccf.ru/_xpack/watcher/watch/audit_watch`.

Comment: @harishkb https://es.origin-test.cloud.rccf.ru/_xpack/watcher/watch/audit_watch also doesn`t work

Comment: Anna, what's the error?

Comment: @harishkb No handler found for uri [/_xpack/watcher/watch/audit_watch] and method [PUT]

Comment: @harishkb And also one moment : I have elasticsearch 2.4.4 from openshift pack

Comment: You might want to check if xpack is installed. What's the o/p of GET https://es.origin-test.cloud.rccf.ru/_xpack ?

Comment: @harishkb {
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "No feature for name [_xpack]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "No feature for name [_xpack]"
    },
    "status": 400
}

Comment: Looks like x-pack is not installed. Hence you won't be able to create x-pack watcher alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [support matrix](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility), elasticsearch 2.x is not compatible with x-pack.

You might want to install Watcher as a separate plugin using [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/installing-watcher.html) document.